# JSF 2.0 and JPA 2.0 Integration (Dynamic Web Project Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

Background :

Im looking to create JSF 2 and JPA 2 Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse. I have been following a tutorial of JPA 2 Integration and have achieved thee following :

Created a Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse wit Facets - JSF 2 AND JPA 2 selected - attaching all the neccessary JSF 2 Libraries and the following JPA configuration :-

Downloaded EclipseLink 1.2.0 and added (eclipselink.jar and javax.persistence_1.1.0.jar) to classpath.

Downloaded Derby Database and configured it to use with my Eclipse. My Derby Database connection is working correctly with Eclipse as I have recieved a successful Ping. 
The Derby connection details are : 
url       :    jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sampleJPA;create=true
name      :    user
password  :    pass

My folder Java Resources/src/META-INF/persistence.xml is blank as generated, and this is as far as I have got to.

Problem :

The problem is the tutorial I am following and the only examples I can find, is JPA configuration and setup of Java Project - which is not the Dynamic JSF 2 and JPA 2 configuration and setup I require.

Also, I have been following other examples where I have seen Hibernate Library - with around 14 or so .jar configuration files been added in configuration setup for Object Relational Mapping.

Question :

In order to copmplete my JSF 2 and JPA 2 dynamic web project setup -  what files do I need to change, add to complete this goal ?

Is it neccessary to add other Hibernate libraries ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The main issue here is you understood concept of different layer integration wrong. JPA is data layer specification with some persistence provide like `EclipseLink` and `JSF` is view framework. So, there should be some service layer like EJB/CDI or CDI/Restful or Spring.http://technology-for-human.blogspot.com/2011/04/jsf-2-spring-3-jpa-hibernate-3.html. Or if you are familiar with `Maven` you can directly search for `spring-jsf-jpa-archetype`.

Comment: Thanks for that tutorial link - I found it quite helpfull. Mark